# How is Thor still mighty and powerful after Asgard was destroyed?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnorak*, Odin states that Hela draws her power from Asgard, so does Thor (if I remember correctly).

On Earth her costume has multiple tears, signifying her weakened state (maybe it's result from million years imprisoned far away from Asgard). When she arrives on Asgard her outfit is now whole and takes on her traditional green color scheme, showing that she has regained her strength.

That's why unleashing Sultur was an option, so he would destroy Asgard, in order to weaken Hela, and therefore end her.

So, if Thor also draws power from Asgard, how is he still powerful and kicking bad guys in *Infinity War* after Asgard was completely destroyed?

Comment: *"Asgard is not a place, it's a people"*

Comment: If there was a theme of this movie, this was it .... Asgard is a people and Thor's job was to save the people not the place.

Comment: I don't recall it ever being stated that *Thor* draws his power from Asgard, only Hela.

Answer (score 7):

Though, Thor draws his power from Asgard, but it was stated in the movie a couple of times that that Asgard's not a place, it's a people.

> **Thor:** Without my hammer, I can't.
>
> **Odin:** Are you Thor, the God of Hammers? That hammer was to help you control your power, to focus it. It was never your source of strength.
>
> **Thor:** It's too late. She's already taken Asgard.
>
> **Odin:** **Asgard is not a place. Never was. This could be Asgard. Asgard is where our people stand.** Even now, right now, those people need your help.

Later Thor says this to Loki.

> **Thor:** **Asgard's not a place, it's a people.** Loki, this was never about stopping Ragnarok. This was about causing Ragnarok.

Since he saved his people (though half of them died in IW), he can still have his powers. However, this fact shouldn't be forgotten that Thor got his powers in heritage.

<sub>[Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=thor-ragnarok)</sub>

Comment: Seeing how too little Hela cared for the people of Asgard (She slaughtered like a lot of them since her return) I’m guessing she drew her power from the _physical_ realm Asgard. But again, if _Asgard is not a place, it's the people_, then survivors of Asgard could build another one, but since there are not many of them left ... Anyway, it's not clear in the movie

Comment: Yes, it's not stated in the movie, but it can be concluded that Thor can get power from remaining.

Comment: It's hard to know when people were speaking metaphorically versus literally.  Hela may have gotten her power *literally* from *literal* Asgard (actual planet gives her power she didn't already have), whereas Thor derived power *metaphorically* from *metaphorical* Asgard (he is motivated and driven to protect the people, which pushes him to achieve more and utilize more of his innate power).  In some sense the story was a parable about placing lives and culture above locations and objects (as well as emphasizing Nobility and Wisdom over Power for Thor's ascension).